# how to create a ticket in rt using python-rtkit

Tags: python, rest, rt

I'm having trouble with a simple script whose only purpose is to create a single ticket and every time I get

```
401 Credentials Required
```

I took my code verbatim from https://github.com/z4r/python-rtkit. (URL, username and password are redacted for security reasons)

```
from rtkit.resource import RTResource
from rtkit.authenticators import BasicAuthenticator
from rtkit.errors import RTResourceError

from rtkit import set_logging
import logging
set_logging('debug')
logger = logging.getLogger('rtkit')

resource = RTResource('http://rt.example.com/REST/1.0/', 'user', 'pass', BasicAuthenticator)

#create a ticket
content = {
    'content': {
        'Queue': 'General - unassigned', #General - unassigned is the name of the desired queue
        'Subject' : 'Test Ticket Python', #text to go into subject field
        }
    }
try:
    response = resource.post(path='ticket/new', payload=content,)
    logger.info(response.parsed)
except RTResourceError as e:
    logger.error(e.response.status_int)
    logger.error(e.response.status)
    logger.error(e.response.parsed)
```

Here's the output I get from this

```
[DEBUG] POST ticket/new
[DEBUG] {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8', 'Accept': 'text/plain'}
[DEBUG] 'content=Queue: General - unassigned\nSubject: Test Ticket Python'
[INFO] POST
[INFO] http://rt.example.com/REST/1.0/ticket/new
[DEBUG] HTTP_STATUS: 200 OK
[DEBUG] 'RT/3.6.6 401 Credentials Required\n'
[DEBUG] RESOURCE_STATUS: 401 Credentials required
[INFO] []  
[INFO] []
```

Anyone know how to fix this?  I just need to be able to make tickets with python.  So alternatively other methods of doing this that don't use python-rtkit is fine as long as it reaches the end goal.

EDIT:
Opening the url from my browser (after logging in) yields

```
RT/3.6.6 200 Ok

# Invalid object specificaiton: 'index.html'

id: index.html
```

Opening the url from my browser (before logging in) yields

```
RT/3.6.6 401 Credentials Required
```

I'm not particularly knowledgeable about anything internet so I'm not sure how to look at the server's header that's returned.  It's worth noting that I have tried Cookie Authentication without any better results.

EDIT:
@Zaroth's request. I'm using https.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>302 Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Found</h1>
<p>The document has moved <a href="https://rt.example.com/REST/1.0/">here</a>.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.3 (Red Hat) Server at rt.hdms.com Port 80</address>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Could you paste output of following command: `curl "http://rt.example.com/REST/1.0/" -d "user=myuser&pass=mypass"`. And possibly specify whether it's HTTP or HTTPS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I don't know why it didn't work the first time but I've managed to get it working now by using CookieAuthentication instead of BasicAuthentication.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the correct URL for your RT web service.

I assume the URL `http://rt.example.com/REST/1.0/` does not point to your running RT instance?

Or have you added rt.example.com to your `hosts` file or similar?

At what host/port does your RT instance run?

Comment: it is a redacted url.  i can't put up my company's actual URL or user/pass for security reasons.  sorry for any confusion.

Comment: OK, so your URL is ``https://servername/REST/1.0/...`` then? What happens if you try to open the URL from a browser? Could you try that and have a look at the response headers from the server? Perhaps your setup uses another authentication scheme (ie. not basic authentication)?