# Create ticket in RT with python-rtkit having RESOURCE_STATUS: 401 Credentials required

Tags: python, rest, rt

I'm new here. It's the same question as this one, but I didn't get answer so I post it again: [how to create a ticket in rt using python-rtkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890098/how-to-create-a-ticket-in-rt-using-python-rtkit)

I tried both `CookieAuthenticator` and `BasicAuthenticator` to create or read ticket but I still get the same error:

```
`RT/3.8.13 401 Credentials required`
```

When I load the url directly in the browser: http://ticket.corp.kk.net/REST/1.0/ticket/214560?user=user&pass=pass, I DO get the ticket content in the browser.

I even tried the `wget` command to get one ticket content as below using cookie, and it works well:

1. save manually the cookie value in the `coookie.txt` file:

   ```
   RT_SID_kk.net.80=5a1c1eb207c4e2ef5af726e98d751a08
   ```
2. run this command:

   ```
   wget -O ticketContent.txt --keep-session-cookies --save-cookies cookies.txt 'http://ticket.corp.kk.net/REST/1.0/ticket/220680/show?format=l&user=user&pass=pass'
   ```

The ticket content is well registered in `ticketContent.txt`, which is showing using the cookie to authenticate is working.

But I still can not go through `CookieAuthentication` of rtkit in my python script.

I've been struggling on this problem for 2 days, I would deeply appreciate it if someone can help me out. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to create a ticket in rt using python-rtkit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17890098/how-to-create-a-ticket-in-rt-using-python-rtkit)

Answer (score 1):

I haven't found a solution for this problem , but I succeeded to use python Requests library to create a ticket in RT .

1. install Requests lib. http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/install/#install
2. create a new ticket in RT

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/python -u
   import requests,logging

   logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
   post_data = """
   id: ticket/new
   Queue: myqueue
   Subject: Test Ticket creation in RT with Python
   Text: Wow ticket is created :-D . 
   """
   payload = {'user': 'user', 'pass': 'password','content':post_data}
   ticket_creation_reusult = requests.post("http://ticket.corp.kk.net/rt3/REST/1.0/ticket/new", payload)

   logging.debug(ticket_creation_reusult.text)
   ```

The output is:

```
INFO:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:Starting new HTTP connection (1):  ticket.corp.kk.net
DEBUG:requests.packages.urllib3.connectionpool:"POST /rt3/REST/1.0/ticket/new     HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG:root:RT/3.8.13 200 Ok
# Ticket 221173 created.
```

Hope this can help you , if you have the same problem as me . :-)